# How to re-ask a quesion if the original accepted answer is irrelevant?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This could apply to many situations, but here's just one:

Say Alice asks a question on SO saying "how do I do X?".  Bob then answers the question with "use library Y", and provides a link to the Y page.

Fast-forward several months later, where library Y is outdated and no longer maintained, and the official site that Bob linked to is 404'd.  Carol needs to do X, but can't use library Y like Bob's answer suggested, but she can't post to SO because it'll be closed as a exact duplicate of Alice's question.

Comment: Similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38491/what-to-do-about-permanently-outdated-questions-answers-on-su

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a situation as cut and dry as you describe, she posts "How do I do X now that Y has gone belly-up?", and links the original with a brief explanation of the problem.

Or, if she has the rep she can edit the original question and/or original answer to bump that question to the top of the active stack and get more attention.

Comment: I would favour asking a new question and linking rather than editing the existing one. Bumping a question that's been answered already won't get it much attention especially from people who watch the unanswered tab.