# Duplicate question answers no longer work/apply, new user cannot assign bounty to duplicate

Tags: support, bounties, duplicate-questions

On [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) the question [How to reference a cell while keeping its color formatting?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127674/how-to-reference-a-cell-while-keeping-its-color-formatting) references an older question [Cell reference with colour formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/cell-reference-with-colour-formatting) (duplicate), and the OP remarks *the answer seems to be not working anymore*.

The proper way to handle this is to not write a new duplicate question, but to put a bounty on the old one.

However, OP is a new user, (s)he can't assign a bounty.

What is the proper follow up now?
Should the newer question still be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be marked as a duplicate, at least for the time being. See [If you are not satisfied with answers on someone else's question, should you ask your own?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20042/if-you-are-not-satisfied-with-answers-on-someone-elses-question-should-you-ask)

Comment: Similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48112/how-to-re-ask-a-quesion-if-the-original-accepted-answer-is-irrelevant